# What is the union of two matrices and its notion?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrix-rank

> Q1. Is the union of matrices $A$ and $B$ denoted by $A|B$?

The following example is taken from a monograph  by M. Hazewinkel entitled "Handbook of Algebra", Volume 6 
Published by North Holland, (2009)
ISBN: 0444532579,9780444532572.

> Example 6.29. Let us consider the following two matrices
>   $
>     A=\begin{bmatrix}
>         0 & 1 & 0 \\
>         0 & 0 & 1 \\
>          0& 0 & 1 \\
>          0 & 1 &  0
>       \end{bmatrix}
>     $, $
>     B=\begin{bmatrix}
>         0 & 0 & 0 \\
>         0 & 0 & 0 \\
>          1 & 0 & 0 \\
>          1 & 0 &  0
>       \end{bmatrix}.$
>   Then it is straight forward to  see that  $r(A)=2$, $r(B)=1$. Then  it holds that $r(A|B)=4>3=r(A)+r(B)$.

---

> Q2. What is the union of  two matrices?

According to what i think about a matrix union, the union of the given mattrices should have been 
  $$A|B=\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
         1& 0 & 1 \\
         1 & 1 &  0
      \end{bmatrix}
    $$
Therefore, its rank should have been 
$r(A|B)=3$ but not $4$

Comment: @Bungo According to my interpretation, rank of the union of $A$ and $B$, which i supposed to have been denoted by $r(A|B)$ is $3$, but not $4$.

Comment: @Bungo Is the matrix $[A|B]$ is called union of $A$  and $B$? The matrix $[A|B]$ in this sense will have 8 rows and 6 columns. Isn't? Still it's rank should be $3$ not $4$.

Comment: @Bungo It's not really clear what $A|B$ is. It is neither represented nor defined clearly in this book. But it probably denote union of $A$ and $B$. I also couldn't understand as to what is the role of entries being from a semiring in the union of the matrices.

Comment: @gete I think the author tried to find the inverse of $\ A$ matrix by introducing row operations. But I really don't understand how he obtained $\ A|B$ like this.

Comment: Please give the reference in readable form, not via a link.

Comment: @quid How to do that?

Comment: Write what book or article it is from, title and author.

Comment: @gete: It is unreasonable to ask people to download illegal copies of a book. It is also very reasonable to learn how to properly cite a text.

Comment: I don't need instructions how to access it. Please do what I asked for. To the extent possible the post should make sense independent of links; what if the target of the link goes down at some point.

Comment: @quid I tried to improve the style of referencing in the way as it is done.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for your guidance here

Comment: Thank you; it seems very good to me.